# Populate H2 in-mem db from .csv file using scala slick

Tags: scala, csv, h2, slick

### Context

- **Given** the following Slick database schema

```scala
class Suppliers(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {

  // This is the primary key column:
  def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street: Rep[String] = column[String]("STREET")
  def city: Rep[String] = column[String]("CITY")
  def state: Rep[String] = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip: Rep[String] = column[String]("ZIP")
  
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] =
    (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}
```

- **And** the following `.csv` sample file

```
101, "Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199"
49, "Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place", "Mendocino", "CA", "95460"
150, "The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane", "Meadows", "CA", "93966"
```

- **When** I setup and try to load the `.csv` file (*whose path is received as a system property*)

```scala
object HelloSlick extends App {

  val csvPath = System.getProperty("csvPath")

  val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem")
  try {

    val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]

    val setup: DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
      suppliers.schema.create,
      sqlu"INSERT INTO SUPPLIERS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD($csvPath)"
    )
    
    val resultFuture = db.run(setup)

    Await.result(resultFuture, Duration.Inf)

  } finally db.close
}
```

- **Then** the db is created and the `.csv` data is loaded succesfully

### But...

Actually what it is happening is:

```
09:49:39.553 [DEBUG] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: INSERT INTO SUPPLIERS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD(?)
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Parameter "fileName" is not set; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO SUPPLIERS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD(?) [90012-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:587)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.expression.function.Function.getValueForColumnList(Function.java:2702)
    at org.h2.table.FunctionTable.<init>(FunctionTable.java:60)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFunction(Parser.java:1945)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1892)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:2641)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2788)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2636)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:2469)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2440)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsertGivenTable(Parser.java:1759)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1684)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:891)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:788)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:760)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:683)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:565)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1292)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:77)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:349)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:375)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef.prepareStatement$(JdbcBackend.scala:365)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:489)
    at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:33)
    at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
    at slick.jdbc.Invoker.first(Invoker.scala:30)
    at slick.jdbc.Invoker.first$(Invoker.scala:29)
    at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.first(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
    at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:52)
    at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:51)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anon$4.$anonfun$run$3(DBIOAction.scala:239)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anon$4.run(DBIOAction.scala:239)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anon$4.run(DBIOAction.scala:237)
    at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:276)
    at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:276)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

### Question

*How could I **fix**, **bypass** or **workaround** this behaviour in order to **be able to pass the `.csv` path as parameter**?*

> If I put directly the `.csv` path in the CSVREAD string sentence, everything works as expected.
>
> ```
> sqlu"INSERT INTO SUPPLIERS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('/home/foo/sample.csv')"
> ```
>
> Something happens when `sqlu` interpolation comes into action.

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.10",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.199"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `'$csvPath'` with plain `$csvPath`. JDBC parameters are values and cannot be included into string literals.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the quotes are not necessary, but the code is still not working. I just updated the post with the exception got. ANy idea?

Comment: It looks like table value functions of H2 don't support parameters. So you need a workaround. Try `'#$csvPath'`, it should inline the passed parameter. But you'll need to replace `'` with `''` (two characters) in csvPath, if `'` character is possible in that string.

Comment: I filled a new issue about that problem on bugtracker of H2: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2634