# Scala on Intellij: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: scala, jdbc, mariadb, slick

reference of code: [Populate H2 in-mem db from .csv file using scala slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893544/populate-h2-in-mem-db-from-csv-file-using-scala-slick)

I want to insert id,timestamp, and social_media from csv to mysql. But there's an Error on my SQL syntax, I don't understand how to solve this
here's my code & error:

```
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._
import slick.lifted.ProvenShape
import java.sql.Timestamp
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Insertion extends App{ 
class rk_post(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Timestamp, String)](tag, "rk_post") {
   def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)

   def timestamp = column[Timestamp]("timestamp")

   def social_media = column[String]("social_media")

   def * : ProvenShape[(Int, Timestamp, String)] =
       (id, timestamp, social_media)
}
  val csvPath = System.getProperty("src/main/resources/rk_post_made_0.csv")

  val db = Database.forConfig("mysql") 

 try {

 val rk_post = TableQuery[rk_post]

 val setup: DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
   rk_post.schema.create,
   sqlu"INSERT INTO RK_POST SELECT * FROM CSVREAD($csvPath)"
)

val resultFuture = db.run(setup)

Await.result(resultFuture, Duration.Inf)


 } finally db.close

}
```

**> Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"rk_post" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"timestamp" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,"...' at line 1**

Comment: What is `CSVREAD` supposed to be doing in your query?  This does not look like valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: so the problem are from sqlu"INSERT INTO RK_POST SELECT * FROM CSVREAD($csvPath)" ?

Comment: 1) you are using mariadb and not mysql. No, the two are not the same, only similar. If your ORM follows mysql syntax while you are using mariadb, then it can cause syntax errors. 2) The syntax error comes from the create table statement that the ORM generates based on your scala code. You need to log the entire statement to see what goes wrong and based on that you can fix the scala code.

Comment: Case where there is no benefit from using ORM, native SQL query ...

Comment: hmm but I build the connection with mySQL Server, I've checked my server status on mySQL Workbench and status server are running.
Here's some detail of my connection:
Host: ASUS
Socket: C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock
Port: 3306
Version: 10.4.24-MariaDB (mariadb.org binary distribution)

Comment: Version: 10.4.24-**MariaDB**

Comment: I thought I'm using MySQL because I build the connection in mySQL Server, thank you I'll try to find the solution and example of mariadb implementation on scala-slick

Comment: It seems that you're trying to use a mysql driver class to connect, but use slick H2 query synatx because of `import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._`

Is your config and import package correct?
see slick docs: https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/database.html


http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvread

Comment: Yeah I've already made mysql application.conf based on that site. The **import slick,jdbc.H2Profile.api._** are required to define class rk_post, so I'm using that import package